# How to get Azure storage account Infrastructure encryption status in powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, encryption, azure-devops, azure-storage-account

I am trying to check the Infrastructure encryption status via powershell. Here is the screenshot [Encryption](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrFH9.png)

I referenced this doc("https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/infrastructure-encryption-enable?tabs=portal") and tried the below script but didn't get any result.

> $account = Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName  `
> -StorageAccountName  $account.Encryption.RequireInfrastructureEncryption

Is there a way to see if the Infrastructure encryption is enabled or disabled?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From that [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/infrastructure-encryption-enable?tabs=portal), there are two kinds of encryption levels for Azure storage account, at the **service level** and at the **infrastructure level**. By default, Azure Storage automatically encrypts all data in a storage account at the service level using 256-bit AES encryption, customers who require higher levels of assurance that their data is secure can also enable 256-bit AES encryption at the Azure Storage infrastructure level.

To doubly encrypt your data, you **must first create a storage account that is configured for infrastructure encryption**.

In this case, if you have not enabled the infrastructure encryption, you could see the `"requireInfrastructureEncryption": null` with Azure CLI.

```
az storage account show --name <storage-account> --resource-group <resource-group>
```

[image]

To Verify that infrastructure encryption is enabled, you could Register to use infrastructure encryption,

```
Register-AzProviderFeature -ProviderNamespace Microsoft.Storage `
    -FeatureName AllowRequireInfraStructureEncryption
```

Create an account with infrastructure encryption enabled,

```
New-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName <resource_group> `
    -AccountName <storage-account> `
    -Location <location> `
    -SkuName "Standard_RAGRS" `
    -Kind StorageV2 `
    -RequireInfrastructureEncryption
```

Then you can Verify that infrastructure encryption is enabled with the PowerShell scripts.

```
$account = Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName <resource-group> `
    -StorageAccountName <storage-account>
$account.Encryption.RequireInfrastructureEncryption
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation! it helped :)

Comment: @Nanxy Xiong, if it is disabled do I get false as a return value?

Comment: From that Azure CLI result, you will see by default if it is disabled, you get null instead of false as a return value, you can check it with PowerShell `$result = $account.Encryption.RequireInfrastructureEncryption -eq $null`

Comment: Please be aware, that you have to enable Infrastructure Encryption during the initial creation of a Storage Account! You cannot enable it later.